# Possible in ruby on rails 3 to retrieve sums for multiple columns in one query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sum

I want to get the sums for a dozen columns in a table.

```
# result will be {:a => 340.5, :b => 21.8, ... }
# where :a has the sum of the :a column values
# entries is an ActiveRecord model, e.g. ScoreCard.where(:user => user)
def self.totals(entries)
  [:a, :b, :c, :d, :e, :f, :g, :h, :i, :j, :k, :m].inject({}) do |tv, col|
     tv[col] = entries.sum(col)
     tv
  end
end
```

Is there a way to do this in one query?  The above generates a dozen queries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something with manually overriding the `select` values like this, which would run a single query returning all of your sums as fields:

```
sums = entries.select("sum(a) as a, sum(b) as b, ....").first
tv[:a] = sums[:a]
tv[:b] = sums[:b]
# etc....
```

Comment: entries.select([:a, :b, :c, :d, :e, :f, :g, :h, :i, :j, :k, :m].collect { |col| "sum(#{col}) as #{col}" }.join(',')).first  works like a charm.  Thank you!

Comment: just watch that you don't have a nil when you don't want one. I used `sum(coalesce(quantity, 0)` to get around that. thanks for the answer and question.